# Magento 2 module does not showing , getting error unknnow module

Tags: magento2

I am using Klarna magento 2 module,My module is  in App/code direcotry. below is my  registration.php file

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @category    NWT
 * @package     NWT_Base
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 Nordic Web Team ( http://nordicwebteam.se/ )
 * @license     NWT Commercial License (NWTCL 1.0)
 *
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'NWT_Base',
    __DIR__
);
```

And here is composer file

```
{
  "name": "nwt/base",
  "description": "NWT Base module",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "license": "NWTCL 1.0",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "NWT\\Base\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to short out this issue . please help me

Comment: Did you run setup upgrade? Which error you met?

Comment: I did  magento setup:upgrade  no error will found,  but still same issue

Comment: You can post your module with the path?

Comment: Let me know how can i post zip file

Comment: Have u put `etc\module.xml`?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/ Follow to Create Magento 2 Module

Comment: Have you check in db setup_module table, NWT_Base entry generate or not?

Comment: @SanjayYadav you can check simple module sample here https://github.com/kingsatti/Simple-HelloWorld-Module-Magneto2 and check what are you missing